# How to Declare and execute storedprocedure in powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

I tried to Declare a stored procedure in powerbuilder.after i selecting the list of currently available  stored procedure and suppling the parameters.the declaration statement is pasted into my script and then i use EXECUTE test_proc();.powerbuilder show the error "undefined variable Test_proc".
can any one help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without any of your code or knowing which database you are using I can only provide the following from the PowerBuilder Help:

```
Given this procedure:

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spu_edt_object(
o_id_object OUT NUMBER,
o_message OUT VARCHAR2,
a_id_object NUMBER,
a_param VARCHAR2 := NULL,
a_value VARCHAR2 := NULL) as
begin
o_id_object := 12345;o_message := 'Hello World';
end;

The DECLARE statement must use named notation because output parameters are defined to the left of input parameters:

dec{0} o_id_object, id_obiect = 54321
string o_message, param = 'Test'
DECLARE proc_update PROCEDURE FOR spu_edt_object (
a_id_object => :id_object,
a_param => :param)
USING SQLCA;

EXECUTE proc_update;
if SQLCA.SqlCode = 0 then
   //do some error stuff
RETURN -1
end if
FETCH proc_update INTO :o_id_object, o_message;
if SQLCA.SqlCode = 0 then
   //do some error stuff
RETURN -1
end if
```

Comment: Thank you..it helps me a lot

Comment: @Remi: If it addressed your issue, you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/65088/173356)

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server using the Native SQL Server client, you will have to modify your declare statement. PowerBuilder will not like the parenthesis, and you might need to add the @ and the keyword `OUTPUT` in addition to changing some of the symbols as shown below:

```
DECLARE proc_update PROCEDURE FOR spu_edt_object     
@o_id_object = :o_id_object OUTPUT,     
@o_message = :o_message OUTPUT,    
@a_id_object = :id_object,    
@a_param = :param    
@a_value = :value
```

You don't need a using, if you are using the default SQLCA transaction object.